# possible to resize a transparent image?

Tags: html, css

I downloaded a transparent image and now would like to change the size on it:

[image]

when I try this it says that it will lose all transparency info. How can I resize this and where can I find a transparent image that serves as a document info icon. The desired size is 30px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparent icons have no issue with html/css, and should be treated the same as any other image. Below are just two options for you to resize the image in css:

You can place it in a `img` tag and resize with css:

```css
html {
  background: lightblue;
}
img {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/3d-transparent-glass-icons-business/076001-3d-transparent-glass-icon-business-document1.png" />
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the `background` property:

```css
html {
  background: tomato
}
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: url(http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/3d-transparent-glass-icons-business/076001-3d-transparent-glass-icon-business-document1.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try with modern approach these day, just include lightweight, cross browser fontawesome library or use cdn for icons fonts. See the link for fontawesome icons.
```

http://codepen.io/krunalv/pen/OPwzpo
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/